# Interacting with a smart contract

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, transactions, action, javascript

How can a user interact with the contract? Is typing the command `cleos push action` the only option?

Comment: that's just a wrapper for interacting with the abi of the contract. you can use any wrapper (e.g. eosjs methods) as long as the correct bytes are communicated to `nodeos`

Answer (score 2):

Like Patrick said you need to build a front end to communicate with smart contracts on the eosio blockchain. Here a couple of library's to get you started. I have seen a few others as well. Just search eosio on github and look around, there is always new libraries and boilerplates popping up. https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js  https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs

Comment: A demux pattern boilerplate example can be found here: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio-project-demux-example

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea is that you create a web front end using react. The user probably doesn't ever see there is a contract or even blockchain behind the webpage

Answer (score 1):

Create front end and make it interecting with contract using eosiojs